# Keyboard shortcut to switch to specific app in OS X

Tags: macos, keyboard-shortcuts, dock

In Windows, I can switch to an open app, or an app that has a shortcut pinned to the taskbar, using the shortcut <kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>{num}</kbd>, where `num` is the index of the app in the taskbar.

For example, if I've pinned Google Chrome as the first item, I can always launch Chrome or switch to it by pressing <kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>1</kbd>.

Is there any similar shortcut available for Mac OS X? I'd like to switch in the same way to the n-th app in the Dock.

Comment: You can switch to a specific Space. If you pin apps to Spaces, that's a fast method of switching.

Comment: You can create this functionality in macOS, since one can create keyboard shortcuts that are attached to scripts.  However, since you want them numbered, it would mean having to create, say, 10  individual scripts and shortcuts: one for ⟨⌘⟩+⟨1⟩, another for ⟨⌘⟩+⟨2⟩, and so on...

Comment: [Switching to spaces with keyboard](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/213549/keyboard-shortcuts-for-switching-spaces) and [assigning apps to spaces](https://support.apple.com/en-ca/guide/mac-help/work-in-multiple-spaces-mh14112/mac).

Comment: @idbrii That's for multiple spaces. I want to use the same space. I have two screens and I want to switch to another app on the other screen without accidentally typing terminal commands into a chat app.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Have you tried using [Snap](https://apps.apple.com/us/app/snap/id418073146?mt=12) from the App Store?

FEATURES:
Snap automatically assigns keyboard shortcuts to apps pinned in your dock using a modifier key (command, option, control, or shift) and the number keys. For example, **command+1 opens the 1st app in your dock, command+2 the 2nd, etc**. Rearrange or add new apps to the dock and the shortcuts will automatically reset.

Comment: Great, thank you, Arman, it's a nice tool and it does what I wanted.

Comment: Awesome! No worries. 

Comment: Open Snap MacOS app> "Automatic" tab > Tap "Command" to unbind the cmd+1 hotkey (useful for Chrome tab switching)

Answer (score 3):

I've used [Apptivate](http://www.apptivateapp.com/) (free and OS X 10.9+) to accomplish this for a few years. It allows you to assign apps to arbitrary keyboard shortcuts, so I assign them in the same order they appear in my dock: Vim to Option+1, Finder to Option+2, Terminal to Option+3...

> Apptivate: create global hotkeys for your files and applications.
>
> - Launch, activate, hide and quick peek applications
> - Execute scripts
> - Run Automator workflows
> - Instantly access files and folders

Comment: Small note: not to forget to grant permissions to this app (Security & Privacy  -> Accessibility -> Check Apptivate).

Comment: Additionally, it is worth trying to check "Allow overriding system shortcuts" in Apptivate Preferences if it does not accept a desired shortcut.